# Limits And Definitions

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$, sometimes in many cases we say that $f(x)$ approaches $L$ by taking all the intermediate values. So I want to know that can we say that a function $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x \to c^+$ by taking all the intermediate value if there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $a$ satisfying $L < a < L +\epsilon$, $f(x)$ takes all intermediate values in the interval $[a, L+ \epsilon]$ for $x$ lying in $(c, c+ \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$

Comment: What if $f$ is constant?

Comment: For a constant $f$ the above condition is not satisfied so it approaches $L$ but not by taking all intermediate values

Answer (score 1):

Forget about "approaching". Sure, it is a useful mental image, but let's take the formal definition:

We say $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) =L$ if for all $\epsilon \ge 0$ there is $\delta$ so that whenever $0  <\lvert x - c \rvert \le \delta$ ($x$ is near $c$, but is not $c$), $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \le \epsilon$ ($f(x)$ is near $L$). The value of $\epsilon$ governs how near $L$ we want $f(x)$ to be. Picture a strip $L \pm \epsilon$ we want $f(x)$ to be contained in, then there is a strip $c \pm \delta$ (excluding $c$) in $x$ for which the above es true.